# The sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{10k+5\over (k+1)!2^k}$

Tags: summation

I'm solving a problem, and I'm getting the following sum as the solution. $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{10k+5\over (k+1)!2^k}$$

Wolfram Alpha says this [can be simplified](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%20%2810k%2b5%29/%28%28k%2b1%29!%2a2%5Ek%29,%20k=1..%28n-1%29). How do I arrive at the result? I believe I've calculated similar sums in the past, but now I'm completely stumped.

Is there an elementary method to do it? Wolfram Alpha's result doesn't involve any symbols that a high school student wouldn't underdstand so maybe it's doable by elementary means?

**Added.** I think I made a mistake in obtaining the sum, and it should be $2^{k+1}$ in the denominator instead of $2^k$. I don't know if it changes anything. People were saying something about changing $(k+1)!$ to $k!$ in the comments, so maybe it does, but I completely don't see it. The expression Wolfram Alpha gives now isn't any simpler.

Comment: Try $10k+5 = 10(k+1) - 5$ and split into two sums in one of which $(k+1)!$ can be replaced by $k!$?

Comment: Try a clever form of zero. You have $10k$ in the numerator and a factor of $k+1$ in the denominator. What can you do to kill off the factor of $10k$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for the comment. Could you be more explicit about what I should be trying to achieve? I'm not sure what "kill off the factor of $10k$" means, and why I want to do that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you. Why is $k!$ better than $(k+1)!$?

Comment: One possible technique is to use [Gosper's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks. I will look into that, but I don't even know what the word "hypergeometric" means. Isn't there an elementary way to do it?

Comment: @Bartek "Why is $k!$ better than $(k+1)!$? Because the sum $\sum \frac{2^{-k}}{k!}$ is part of the exponential series for $e^{-2}$ and perhaps something might be done with that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for replying. I was thinking about looking at infinite series, but I don't know what they could have to do with the finite sum other than that the finite sums approximate the infinite sum. What could be a general way to use an infinite series here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{10k+5}{2^k(k+1)!}} & =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{10k+10}{2^k(k+1)!}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{5}{2^k(k+1)!}} \\
& =10\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}}-10\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}} \\
& =10\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}}-10\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}} \\
& =10(\frac{1}{2^11!}-\frac{1}{2^nn!}) \\
& =5-\frac{10}{2^nn!}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you arrive at the second to last line?

Comment: @joejacobz \begin{align} & 10\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}}-10\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}} \\ & =[10(\frac{1}{2^11!})+10\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}}]-[10(\frac{1}{2^nn!})+10\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{2^kk!}}] \end{align}